# How to keep value between intents

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an actions on google with fullfillment implemented as firebase function.

I am using app.data object to keep values between intents. This was working, but now it's forgetting and I am getting "undefined".

In the first intent I store the value I got from user and I ask for confirmation

```
app.intent('intent1', (conv, {myValue}) => {

        //CLEAN AND STORE THE VALUE
        conv.data.myValue = myValue.replace(/[\W_]+/g,'').toUpperCase();


        //ASK USER TO CONFIRM
        conv.contexts.set(Contexts.CONFIRM_YES_NO, 1);      
        //THIS WORKS OK AND THE VALUE IS DISPLAYED CORRECTLY
        conv.ask(`I heard ${conv.data.myValue}, is this correct?`);
        conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes'));
        conv.ask(new Suggestions('No'));

});
```

In the second intent I want to re-use the original value, but am getting "undefined":

```
app.intent('confirm_yes', (conv) => {   
        //RETURNS "UNDEFINED"
        console.log(conv.data.myValue);

});
```

What's happening here? This approach used to work, until today when I upgraded firebase-tools@3.18.6. I did make additional changes, so not sure if I broke it or Google...

Answer (score 1):

SO is so amazing, as soon as I posted a question, my brain figured out the answer!

Anyway, I am not using output context for the yes/no intent, but instead of deleting the output context name (blue x in the picture), I deleted the entire output context (red x in the picture).

This broke it... Apparently, when you delete the output context completely, the context is reset. I don't fully understand the contexts I guess...

[image]